# How can I reverse the contents of a queue

Tags: java

I want the program to print in the output Reversing the **contents of the queue, (use an array hint)**

**I have 3 classes , Node , class , main**

```
public class QueuePtr {
Node front, rear;

QueuePtr ()  { rear = front = null;  }

Boolean isEmpty () 
{
if (front == null)  return true;  else return false;
}
void ENQUEUE (int x) {
Node N = new Node(x);  
if(rear != null) {rear.next = N;
                       rear = N;  }
   else { front = rear = N;   } 
}
int  FRONT (){
if (!isEmpty ()) return front.data;    
else {System.out.println(" error queue is empty"); 
        return -1111;  }
}
void DEQUEUE (){
if (isEmpty ()) System.out.println(" error queue is empty");  
   else if (front == rear) front = rear = null;   
         else  front = front.next;  

public static void main(String arg[])
{
QueuePtr Q = new QueuePtr () ;
   Q.ENQUEUE(10);
   Q.ENQUEUE(20);
   Q.ENQUEUE(30);
   Q.ENQUEUE(40);
  Reverse (Q);
}
```

output
[40,30,20,10]

Comment: Use a Stack instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse method reverses elements of a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857276/reverse-method-reverses-elements-of-a-queue)

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. Java method names go camelCase, like isEmpty ... not ENQUEUE! Also focus on meaningful names. Q isnt really that. Finally: also use meaningful names for your classes. Java doesnt really have "pointers", so a better name would be "MyQueue", just as example.

Comment: Well, if you just have a normal queue (and a custom implementation) you only can iterate from front to back so you'd need to consider that when building the output string (e.g.  prepend the element' s `toString()` result instead of appending or directly printing it). If you want to iterate backwards then you will need a double ended queue (or add the elements in reverse order in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to print your queue in reverse order as you deconstruct it:

```
public static void printBackwards(QueuePtr q) {
    if (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node r = q.DEQUEUE();
        printBackwards(q);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't supply that function, but only referenced in earlier code that you've since removed, I can't help you with that.  It seems pretty obvious to me what it does, but since I don't have all your code, I can't really know.